# WebSphere 8.5.5 Error: PLGC0049E: The propagation of the plug-in configuration file failed for the Web server

Tags: web-services, websphere, websphere-8

I just installed a new WebSphere 8.5.5 ESB on Linux Centos 7.
All installation i did with root user.

Than i did the following steps to create a Web Service:
1) create server with user wasadmin
2) Generate plugin
3) Propagate plugin

In the last step i get the error:

PLGC0049E: The propagation of the plug-in configuration file failed for the Web server. test2lsoa01-02Node01Cell.XXXXXXXXX-node.IHSWebserver.
Error A problem was encountered transferring the designated file. Make sure the file exists and has correct access permissions.

The file /u01/apps/IBM/WebSphere/profiles/ApplicationServerProfile1/config/cells/test2lsoa01-02Node01Cell/nodes/XXXXX-node/servers/IHSWebserver/plugin-cfg.xml exist.
I gave him for test chmod 777 plugin-cfg.xml

Still the error is not going away. 
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

User wsadmin would be the user attempting to move the file. Ensure that ID can access /u01/apps/IBM/WebSphere/profiles/ApplicationServerProfile1/config/cells/test2lsoa01-02Node01Cell/nodes/XXXXX-node/servers/IHSWebserver/plugin-cfg.xml and there should be a target directory as well (in the webserver installation where plugin-cfg.xml is being moved to). Ensure that wsadmin has write access to this target location if propagating using node sync. If using IHS admin, ensure that the userid/password defined in the web server definition has write access to the target location.

A good test would be to access the source plugin-cfg.xml using wsadmin userid and attempt to manually move the file to the target location with the appropriate ID (based upon use of node sync or IHS admin).